# How to catch both OSError and FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, exception

In the code I'm working on I'm catching some exceptions for when the user enters file names to load data from or save data to. What I want is to display different messages in case a file name is invalid on Windows (for example "///") and in the case the requested file does not exist.

The problem: if I try to catch `OSError` to trigger when invalid file name entered it overrides `FileNotFoundError` for example:

```py
filename = input('Please enter filename containing data: ')
try:
    data = load_data(filename)                
except OSError:
    print('Invalid file name. Try again.')
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('File does not exist. Please try again.')
except TypeError:
    print('Please enter a valid file name.')
except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
    print('Invalid file format.')
```

Here if I enter an invalid file name, e.g. `///` or a file name that does not exist - in both cases `OSError` triggers. On the other hand, `JSONDecodeError` is caught properly.

I tried switching `OSError` and `FileNotFoundError` around but still only the `OSError` ever triggers. It is only when I remove OSError completely is when I can actually catch FNFError.

Anyone knows how can I catch both `OSError` and `FNFError` separately?

**EDIT**:
This is what happens when I switch the order of except statements:

```
filename = input('Please enter filename containing data: ')
try:
    data = load_data(filename)    
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('File does not exist. Please try again.')            
except OSError:
    print('Invalid file name. Try again.')
except TypeError:
    print('Please enter a valid file name.')
except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
    print('Invalid file format.')

>>> Please enter filename containing data: ///
Out: File does not exist. Please try again.
```

**EDIT 2:**
This the code for `load_data()`:

```
def load_data(filename: str) -> dict:
    with open(filename, 'r') as jsfile:
        data = json.load(jsfile)
    
    print(f'\nLoaded {len(data.keys())} records.')
    return data
```

Comment: No, this is not what I want since I want to log different errors and print different messages depending on the particular exception caught. @Goion

Comment: Exceptions are in a class hierarchy. Put the `except` block for the more specific types first.

Comment: I think the problem is caused by how you are loading your file with `load_data`, if you use the context manager in opening files i.e. `with open()` switching `FNF` above of `OSError` should do the job.

Comment: @Barmar, I have added info on what happens when I switch OSError and FNFError around. If I do and enter "///" as a file name actually the FNFError triggers, which is of course true, but not the correct description of the issue.

Comment: @BernardL, `load_data()` is a user-defined function but it uses context manager to load data.

Comment: Windows obviously considers it a valid filename or it would raise a different exception.

Comment: @Barmar, it's not wrong of course. It is correct, but in this case I want to notify the user that it's an illegal file name.

Comment: What is `load_data`? And what exceptions it raises?

Comment: @rzlvmp, added the code for `load_data()`. It doesn't raise any exceptions on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change order (`FileNotFoundError` is a subclass of `OSError`) `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Because →

```
for f in ["///", "blahblah"]:
    try:
        open(f, "rb")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('File does not exist: '+f+'. Please try again.')
    except OSError:
        print('Invalid file name: '+f+'. Try again.')
    except TypeError:
        print('Please enter a valid file name: '+f+'.')
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
        print('Invalid file format: '+f+'.')
```

```
Invalid file name: ///. Try again.
File does not exist: blahblah. Please try again.
```

But:

```
for f in ["///", "blahblah"]:
    try:
        open(f, "rb")
    except OSError:
        print('Invalid file name: '+f+'. Try again.')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('File does not exist: '+f+'. Please try again.')
    except TypeError:
        print('Please enter a valid file name: '+f+'.')
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
        print('Invalid file format: '+f+'.')
```

```
Invalid file name: ///. Try again.
Invalid file name: blahblah. Try again.
```

Tested on `Python 3.7.1` at `Linux`

EDIT 1.

Tested behaviour with json.load()

Working as expected →

```
import json

for f in ["///", "blahblah"]:
    try:
        with open(f, 'r') as jsfile:
            data = json.load(jsfile)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('File does not exist: '+f+'. Please try again.')
    except OSError:
        print('Invalid file name: '+f+'. Try again.')
    except TypeError:
        print('Please enter a valid file name: '+f+'.')
```

```
Invalid file name: ///. Try again.
File does not exist: blahblah. Please try again.
```

Are you using Windows? Not sure if `///` bad name for Windows FS (NTFS).
For example `\\\` is a good name for Linux FS

```
import json

for f in ["\\\\\\", "///", "blahblah"]:
    try:
        with open(f, 'r') as jsfile:
            data = json.load(jsfile)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('File does not exist: '+f+'. Please try again.')
    except OSError:
        print('Invalid file name: '+f+'. Try again.')
    except TypeError:
        print('Please enter a valid file name: '+f+'.')
```

```
File does not exist: \\\. Please try again.
Invalid file name: ///. Try again.
File does not exist: blahblah. Please try again.
```

```
$ touch '\\\'
$ ls -l

...
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root        0 May 25 11:59 \\\
...
```

Comment: OP mentioned switching does not work. Also the file input method is different, you are using `open` while OP is using `load_data`.

Comment: So, that means the problem is inside `load_data`? Python working as expected

Comment: `load_data` function uses context manager inside. `with open(filename, 'r') as jsfile:`

Comment: Tested with `with open(..., 'r') as jsfile`

Answer (score 1):

I tried switching OSError and FileNotFoundError and I can catch them as I want. You might want to follow this [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/a7q507/except_oserror_is_also_catching_filenotfound_error/) and recheck your code.